# Calling GetCurrentProcess disregarding the returned value

Tags: c, windows, winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm working on REing a program for school and there are two lines that I can't really seem to figure out.

- First is the program calls `GetCurrentProcess`, and then the next line is:
  `LEA eax, -something-`

  Why would we do something like that? reading up on `GetCurrentProcess` I figured out that it returns a handle to the current process, putting the value of that handle in `eax`.
- Now why would the program delete the value that was returned in `eax` with `lea`? and why would it even call this function if it's not using the returned value at all?

Is there anything else that `GetCurrentProcess` does that would justify it?

Comment: Maybe you want to show us the relevant assembly code you are talking about.

Comment: There really isn't anything to show, the program calls GetCurrentProcess in one line and the next line is lea eax, something. Those two lines alome are the only thing I cannot understand the rest is really irrelevant

Comment: Well, not sure if it's irrelevant. But anyway did you consider the fact that the call to `GetCurrentProcess()` may be just there to confuse the reverse engineer? If you have `...; GetCurrentProcess(); ...` in your C code, you roughly get what you describe: the function is called and the return value is ignored/discarded.

Comment: If you won't show us the code that you want help with there's no point asking. You should remove the entire question if you aren't prepared to share your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under windows operating system you can always access current process through a **pseudo handle** which value is `(HANDLE)-1`. This value is surely what you find loaded directly in `eax` on the second line, but this is also the value that `GetCurrentProcess()` returns.
If I well understood you are reverse engineering a piece of software, in my opinion the original programmer decided to pass from one system to the other, from the constant `(HANDLE)-1` to `GetCurrentProcess()`, or the reverse and forgot to comment out the former choice.
No side effect should be present for any choice you make.
For more info see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx.